# React and Bootstrap: tooltip inside modal (appears behind modal window)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have such code inside file for modal:

```
...
Icon = require 'components/shared/icon'
{ Checkbox, OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } = require 'react-bootstrap'
...
body: ->
...
  <Checkbox
    checked={ @state.myAttr }
    onChange={ @onMyAttrChange }>
    <OverlayTrigger placement='top' overlay={ <Tooltip> {I18n.t('my_attr')} </Tooltip> }>
      <Icon fa='info-circle' style={{ marginLeft: 5' }}  />
    </OverlayTrigger>
  </Checkbox>
```

But tooltip somehow appears **behind** the modal window. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.tooltip` - is tooltip's class by [default](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tooltips-props-tooltip).
So, the solution is to add this:

```
.tooltip { z-index: 1151 !important; }
```

to the file with css for current page. It's issue on the bootstrap side.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following two properties to the component styles:

```
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000 !important;
```